# Is it possible for a function(f) to be $O(f)$ but not $o(f)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is it possible for a function(f) to be $O(f)$ but not $o(f)$? or $o(f)$ but not $O(f)$?

I guess it might be possible for a function that is not monotonically increasing.

Is there an example of this case?

**Added**: Is it correct if I say subtracting  $\theta(f)$  from $O(f)$ equals $o(f)$?

Comment: You mean $O(x)$ and $o(x)$?

Comment: The function $f$ is $O(f)$, but not $o(f)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly: the function $f(x)=x$ is such a function. In fact $f$ is always $O(f)$ and never $o(f)$ (when these both make sense).

**Added:** As Did points out in the comments, I am assuming here that $f$ is not identically $0$ in a neighborhood of the target; in particular, if we’re looking at the behavior of $f$ as $x\to\infty$, I’m assuming that $f$ is not eventually $0$.

Comment: Careful: $f=0$ in a neighborhood of the point is $o(f)$ (true, this is the only case).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the definitions.

$f(x) = O(g(x))$
means there is a constant $C$
such that
$|f(x)| < C |g(x)|$
for $x$ close enough to wherever it is going
($0$, $\infty$, San Jose).

$f(x) = o(g(x))$
means for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$|f(x)| < \epsilon |g(x)|$
for $x$ close enough to wherever it is going.

Therefore,
$f(x) = o(g(x))$ implies that
$f(x) = O(g(x))$.

An intuitive way to see this is that
$f(x) = o(g(x))$
means $f$ is small compared to $g$
and
$f(x) = O(g(x))$
means $f$ is not large compared to $g$.
"small" implies "not large",
but "not large" does not necessarily imply
"small" - it might mean "about the same" 
in a particular case.

Comment: Which topology on the space containing San Jose? :-) (+1)

Comment: I don't know the way to San Jose - I've been away too long.